# Change Asset Path in Android Studio

Tags: android, assets, asset-management

I'd like to change the path for where my assets live. This is because these assets will change often and are shared with other apps (i.e. iOS app) in another build folder.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 4):

To change the asset path you can tell your project to point to a different directory using the sourceSets command in your apps build.gradle file.

Here's how the build.gradle file looks like:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        assets.srcDirs = ['../../../build/android-assets']
    }
}
...
```